# Other data input format than flat json for crossfilter?

Tags: json, dc.js, crossfilter

When using **crossfilter** (for example for dc.js), do I always need to transform my data to a flat JSON for input?

Flat JSON data when reading from AJAX requests tend to be a lot larger than it needs to be (in comparison to for example nested JSON, value to array or CSV data).

Is there an API available which can read in other types than flat json? Are there plans to add those?

I would like to avoid to let the client transform the data before using it.

Comment: Crossfilter takes an array of ... anything you want. Dimension accessors need to return a naturally ordered value based on the elements of that array. That's it. For performance reasons, it's usually better to do any intensive transformations before loading data into Crossfilter rather than performing the transformation in the dimension accessor, but if size is your concern, then the tradeoff is completely up to you.

Comment: As Ethan said, crossfilter takes a JavaScript array - the array doesn't need to come from JSON, it can come from CSV, binary data, whatever you want. It will filter on the elements of that array, but the elements can be as nested as you want (as long as you write the accessors accordingly).